# Why does findViewById return null on an inflated layout in a robolectric-unit-test?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'm trying to test some code with Robolectric.

My code inflates a layout and then tries to retrieve a view by calling `findViewById` on this layout. The layout inflation works fine. However `findViewById` on this layout always returns null.

I can see in the debugger that all the (shadow) child views of the inflated layout are there and have their attributes set. But the id of every child is set to 0. Why is that? Am I missing something?

The actual code on a device or emulator (without robolectric) works fine, but when I try to run it with robolectric it fails as described.

Basically my code looks as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_list_item, null);
TextView view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listItem_date);
//why is view null here!
view.setText("test");
```

Regards
Frank

Comment: what does your layout xml look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, I've found the problem.

My resource identifier `R.id.listItem_date` is declared as `@+id/listItem.date` in my resource xml file.

Android seems to convert the "." in the name to an "_" in the generated R file. This works fine when compiling and running the code but apparently robolectric has problems with this.

When I change the dot in my resource name to an underscore, my robolectric code works fine.

Now that I know what to look for, I've found that there is an open bug ticket for this:
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/issues/265

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following changes

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)**"ContextOnject"**.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_list_item, null);
```